# Do I need to send app to Apple if it is only for my usage?

Tags: ios

Even if I am building an app for my use only do I still need to send it to Apple or can I just install it on my device?

Comment: You only send it to Apple if you want in the App Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting application to store is only to take approval when you need to publish it. Apple also provides a test environment called [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/),  this doesn't need an approval. However, in your case, you can build the application to your phone from Xcode. You don't need any approval for that, only a [provisioning](https://www.google.com/search?q=provision%20file%20ios&oq=provision%20file%20ios&aqs=chrome.0.0l2.3430j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) file for that device in your developer account.

Comment: Yes but in a couple of days app stops working and closes everytime I try to open it.That 's what I dont want. I want to install it on my device and use it without having to recompile it everytime it stops opening...thank you

Comment: That's another problem perhaps the provision file also could be a code problem, that causes a crash, however for the question above this is pretty much the answer.

Comment: I dont think it is a code crash because if I just recompile it again the app starts working(opening) again.

Comment: then probably a provision file problem, you need an apple developer account and register your device provision file.

Comment: I have came across this problem long time ago, and i remember having a provision file solved it for me at least.

Comment: @Eduardo If you are using a free developer account your app will only work for one week before it will stop running and require you to build and deploy again on your device.